# Remove elements from a tuple conditional on other elements

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following tuple

```
text =[('Michael', 'PERSON'), ('Jordan', 'PERSON'), ("'s", 'O'), ('legacy', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('90', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('shows', 'O'), ('that', 'O'), ('he', 'O'), ('was', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('biggest', 'O'), ('player', 'O'), ('ever', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('NBA', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('.', 'O')]
```

The original sentence is "Michael Jordan's legacy in the 90's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA."

And I need to remove the elements classified as 'PERSON'

which I did with

```
new_text = [x for x in text if x[1] != "PERSON"]
sentence= " ".join(x[0] for x in new_text)
print(sentence)
```

the output I get is

```
's legacy in the 90 's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA .
```

please note the `"'s"` in the begining.

Now I am stuck because I need to remove the "'s" elements conditional on the element before being a `"PERSON"`. in this example there are 2 `"'s"` but I only want to remove the one that follows a `"PERSON"`. Any suggestion?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Functional programming way: zip your text with itself moved 1, then you have previous word with you to check. (You still can use normal filter/list comprehension, instead of manual loop, hence it's still functional.)

Comment: Non-functional programming: do a loop over `enumerate(text)` - you'll have both element and its index, so if you come across `'s` you can easily check the previous element.

Comment: If i am not wrong your input is produced from NER Tagger, you can add data cleaning step before giving a text to NER Tagger for tagging. You can simply replace `'s` to `s` in your text

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to loop over both `text` and a shifted version of it using `zip`, and keep a string based on the following conditions:

```
out = []
for i,j in zip(text[:-1], text[1:]):
    if j[0] == "'s":
        if i[1] == 'PERSON':
            continue
        else:
            out.append(j[0])
    else:
        if i[1] != 'PERSON':
            out.append(j[0])
```

---

```
' '.join(out)
"legacy in the 90 's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA ."
```

Answer (score 1):

It is way easier to use a simple for-loop here. Note that `enumerate` is use to retrieve the previous element (`text[pos-1]`), however, this can only be done if a previous element exists (`pos > 0`).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

text =[('Michael', 'PERSON'), ('Jordan', 'PERSON'), ("'s", 'O'), ('legacy', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('90', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('shows', 'O'), ('that', 'O'), ('he', 'O'), ('was', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('biggest', 'O'), ('player', 'O'), ('ever', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('NBA', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('.', 'O')]


new_text = []
for pos, (word, type_) in enumerate(text):
    if type_ == "PERSON":
        # we ignore words of type PERSON
        continue
    if word == "'s" and pos > 0 and text[pos-1][1] == "PERSON":
        # ignore 's if the previous word was of type PERSON
        continue 
    new_text.append((word, type_))


sentence= " ".join(x[0] for x in new_text)
print(sentence)shows
```

Executing this script yields the following text:
`legacy in the 90 's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA .`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `range` and just *look behind* if you find an `O`:

```
text =[('Michael', 'PERSON'), ('Jordan', 'PERSON'), ("'s", 'O'), ('legacy', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('90', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('shows', 'O'), ('that', 'O'), ('he', 'O'), ('was', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('biggest', 'O'), ('player', 'O'), ('ever', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('NBA', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('.', 'O')]

filtered_text = []

for idx in range(len(text)):
  if text[idx][1] == "PERSON":
    continue

  if text[idx][1] == 'O' and idx > 0 and text[idx-1][1] == 'PERSON':
    continue

  filtered_text.append(text[idx][0])

sentence= " ".join(filtered_text)
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = [('', j[1]) if j[0] == "'s" and text[i-1][1]=='PERSON' else j for i, j in enumerate(text)]
print(' '.join([i for i, j in text if j !='PERSON']))
```

Output

```
legacy in the 90 's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA .
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but this works too if it's just one condition to be addressed. A very simple addition to what you already have.

```py
text =[('Michael', 'PERSON'), ('Jordan', 'PERSON'), ("'s", 'O'), ('legacy', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('90', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('shows', 'O'), ('that', 'O'), ('he', 'O'), ('was', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('biggest', 'O'), ('player', 'O'), ('ever', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('NBA', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('.', 'O')]

new_text = [x for idx, x in enumerate(text) if x[1] != "PERSON" and not (idx > 1 and text[idx - 1][1] == "PERSON" and x[0] == "'s")]
sentence= " ".join(x[0] for x in new_text)
print(sentence)
```

The output is as below

```
"legacy in the 90 's shows that he was the biggest player ever in the NBA ."
```